# Best grid/lines to map a group of points

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, computational-geometry, linear-algebra

The data I have is a group of points with their position (x,y) known:

[image]

It is known that all these red dots are situated exactly on the lines which form a grid system like following:

[image]

My object is to find such a grid system that these dots are sitting on.

A few assumptions that help solve the problem:

1. These blue lines are either orthogonal or parallel to each other
2. Suppose the separations between the lines are approximately the same. Namely, each grid is almost a square.
3. The separation is not tiny, or two lines should not be to close to each other. (I don't really have a definition of "too close" sorry.)

I was thinking about some optimization methods that solve for a cost function. I am not sure how to start the problem. Any point is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this problem is "underdetermined" - it means you need additional conditions or some optimization criteria, which would eliminate obvious solutions. You could draw horizontal and vertical line through **each** point and get a grid - will this grid be not good for you? Why?

Comment: Since you mention that two lines should not be too close to each-other, trying to maximize the size of the empty squares in the grid would seem a natural optimization target.